# How to user Minter Role to restrict minting function to Dapp

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm not sure I understand fully how to do this.

I would like for when users to interact with the dapp, it will mint tokens to the user. It is a public function, so to make it so users can't call it directly, I made it role restricted.

This about how far I've gotten. I think I need to use a web3 signed transaction from the approved address?

Comment: Why is it a problem if the users interact with the contract directly?

Answer (score 1):

Hi developer advocate from Chainstack here.

It seems like you are interested in creating a feature called "whitelist". There are plenty of materials online. I copy the following content from this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-whitelist-in-smartcontracts-erc-721-nft-erc-1155-and-others/).

[image]
It's implementation:

```
contract OnChainWhitelistContract is Ownable {

    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;

    /**
     * @notice Add to whitelist
     */
    function addToWhitelist(address[] calldata toAddAddresses) 
    external onlyOwner
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toAddAddresses.length; i++) {
            whitelist[toAddAddresses[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice Remove from whitelist
     */
    function removeFromWhitelist(address[] calldata toRemoveAddresses)
    external onlyOwner
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toRemoveAddresses.length; i++) {
            delete whitelist[toRemoveAddresses[i]];
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice Function with whitelist
     */
    function whitelistFunc() external
    {
        require(whitelist[msg.sender], "NOT_IN_WHITELIST");

        // Do some useful stuff
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

why do you proceed with a public function ?

Isn't it possible to trigger the mint function in another function? (when user do something, if conditions are OK it triggers mint function)

On the question of roles .. dit you think of creating an mapping of structs with user and his stats/authorizations linked to his address ?

With that, when the user triggers the mint function you can easily check in the mapping if he his authorized and if he meets all the required conditions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The thing they do is off-chain though, so I'm not sure how to make it a requirement to mint. Which I guess is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a constructor function, add an owner for the contract in your solidity code, and then in the minting function check if the msg.sender equals the owner. Something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract YourContract {
  address payable owner;
  mapping(address => uint) balance;

  constructor() {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }

  function mint(address _to, uint _amount) public { 
    require(msg.sender == owner, "only the contract owner can mint.");
    
    balance[_to] += _amount;
  }
}
```

Comment: So in theory in the DAPP, I could use this on, for example, a button that the user clicks, sending a signed transaction from the contract owner, to mint these tokens to the user?

Comment: how do plan to mimic a signed transaction from the owner when a user with a different address initiates a tx?